# I have an application which sends email, but I want a clickable link in my email subject

Tags: c#

I have an application which sends email using c#.net, but I want to customize my email subject.
I want subject to be something like this:
Order : OrderId Link : https://myurl/order/orderId
The link should be clickable. I searched on google but could not find anything. 
In MailMessage subject is of datatype string, but link should be clickable.

Any help or tips will be hightly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you mean something like [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/images/carousel-gmail-1.png)?

Comment: This seems like it would be abused if such a feature existed (think spam email)

Comment: no, no, no, no no no no no no no no no. even if possible, this is wrong. this is little different from browser-hijacking. place your links in the message body like any normal, non-malicious person.

Comment: @DGibbs Not sure why a hyperlink in a subject line could be abused for spam. Could see it used to get people to go to fraudulent sites though. Also this is likely a limitation of the email program. I have email accounts with yahoo, gmail, and outlook and none of them as far as i can tell will let me put a hyperlink into the subject. I assume it is a security thing since you generally click on the subject in your email application to open the email. So if it was a clickable hyperlink then people could be easily tricked. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @Jacobr365 I didn't say it could be abused *for* spam... Though it may be abused *by* spam emails, think generating clicks to some spammy SEO site for ad revenue etc... or as you say, a fraudulent site.

Comment: +1 for this question. As I know gamil, yahoo and other shows link as text inside subject to scure it from scams, but I think you can achieve this in outlook desktop application by writting an custom add on for this purpose.